# Configure Log4J 2 programatically using a dynamically generated YAML file

Tags: java, yaml, log4j2

I need to dynamically configure Log4j 2 with a YAML configuration loaded from a web service.

Is there any way to load this configuration?

My best approach has been to download the YAML configuration and write it to a temp file, then make Log4j 2 load it. It is working, but it doesn't feel good.

```
File f = File.createTempFile("config",".yaml");
Files.write(f.toPath(),yamlString.getBytes());
Configurator.initialize(null, f.getAbsolutePath());
f.delete();
Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
LOGGER.info("This is a INFO message");
```

Shortened, I would like to be able to:

```
ConfigurationSource source = new ConfigurationSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(yamlString.getBytes()));
Configurator.initialize(new YamlConfiguration(null,source));
Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
LOGGER.info("This is a INFO message");
```

Comment: Documentation about programmatic configuration: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html#ConfigurationBuilder

Comment: I checked locally with latest versions of log4j and everything is working as expected, maybe the issue is outdated version of dependencies, please provide the dependencies that are used

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet alone is correct, but `Configurator.initialize` does not work if the logger context for the currently running code has already be initialized (e.g. through a static `LogManager.getLogger()` or equivalent).

In such a case you need to reconfigure the logger context:

```java
final org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.LoggerContext apiContext = LogManager.getContext();
// org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext
if (apiContext instanceof LoggerContext) {
    final LoggerContext coreContext = (LoggerContext) apiContext;
    // no configuration explicitly set by the user
    if (coreContext.getConfigLocation() == null)
        coreContext.setConfiguration(new YamlConfiguration(null,source));
    }
}
```